# No puedo Importar "android.database.sqlite"

Tags: android, android-studio, sqlite

Estoy intentando crear una base de datos en Android Studio con sqlite y cuando extiendo una clase de SQLiteOpenHelper estoy intentando importar: 
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper; Pero recibo el error "no se puede resolver el símbolo SQLiteOpenHelper" y no encuentro solución.
En si necesito saber como utilizar e importar las clases que provee android ya que no me deja importar ni una de estas.

```
package com.mygdx.game.entidades;

import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper; //esto es lo que deberia aparecer pero no aparece

public class ConexionSQLite extends SQLiteOpenHelper  {


}
```

Comment: Por favor agrega código para tener mas claro el problema y brindarte una soluciona mas exacta. Puedes utilizar el atajo te teclas `alt+enter` y te importa automáticamente, se que eso no es una respuesta ecertada pero por favor coloca código

Comment: Gracias pero el alt+enter solo me dice que cree la clase "SQLiteOpenHelper", no me deja importarla. ya agregue el codigo aunque no es mucho ya que el error salta al principio cuando creo la clase extendiendo de SQLiteOpenHelper.